# Serving protected files NGINX and Django

Tags: django, nginx

I am trying to serve protected media files with Nginx sendfile and X-Accel-Redirect using Django 2.0.
This is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;
    sendfile    on;

    # Protected media
    location /protected {
        internal;
        alias /Users/username/Documents/sat23/venv/media/;
    }

    # Django static
    location /static {
        alias /Users/username/Documents/sat23/venv/static/;
    }

    # All other requests.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /Users/username/Documents/sat23/venv/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Then in my urls.py I added a simple view that should serve my media files (I'll configure permissions later):

```
def serveMedia(request):
    url = request.path.replace('media', 'protected')
    response = HttpResponse('')
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = url
    response['Content-Type'] = ''
    return response

urlpatterns += [
    path('/media/', serveMedia, name='protected_media')
]
```

However whenever I call `localhost:8000/media/users/user35.jpg`, I just get a Django (not nginx) 404 page, saying that Django tried all the configured paths and it couldn't find the requested one.

So I had a suspicion that my view just doesn't work. I then rewrote it like this:

```
def serveMedia(request):
    return HttpResponse(content=b'Hello there')
```

And sure enough it doesn't get called. But I have no idea why. Could someone help me out?

P.S. Any recommendations on configuring nginx conf are also very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no capturing groups in your Django `path` call there, so that will only match `/media/` verbatim.

You might want to use the old-school `url` route with a regexp like

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'/media/.+', serveMedia),
]
```

to capture everything that starts with `/media/`

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing that out!
I'm using Django 2.0+, so `url()` is deprecated, but that got me thinking and I found the new `re_path()` function that sort of serves this purpose. Added `re_path(r'^media', serveMedia)` and it works!